# Matching similar lists in mysql+php

Tags: php, mysql, search, solr, full-text-search

I have 2 tables, 
first one is **playlists** which includes title, author and date info.
other table is for **tracks** with artist, song name, album (etc.), playlistid, popularity columns.

I would like to show similar playlists for a specific playlist with similarity percentage.

Desired results are like;

- playlist #4 %70 similar to playlist #12
- playlist #4 %62 similar to playlist #9
- playlist #4 %35 similar to playlist #12
- playlist #4 %10 similar to playlist #210

I've tried solr, but I recently discovered SOLR and I am pretty lost in it. Is there way I can do this in mysql?

My only concern is performance. There can be thousands of playlists.
ps:  A playlist is have minimum 5 maximum 10 items/tracks.

Comment: Could you give some more details on how your result should look like. A table with the wished result as well as tables with your test content of your DB would be nice to see and make it much easier to help you..

Comment: Sure, @EdwinKrause question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `tracks` table to itself and then, grouping by playlists, derive your own similarity metric—for example:

```sql
SELECT   t1.playlistid, t2.playlistid,
         (
           1/COUNT(DISTINCT t1.artist, t1.song_name)
         + 1/COUNT(DISTINCT t2.artist, t2.song_name)
         )
         * SUM(t1.artist = t2.artist AND t1.song_name = t2.song_name)/2 similarity
FROM     tracks t1 JOIN tracks t2 ON t2.playlistid > t1.playlistid
GROUP BY t1.playlistid, t2.playlistid
```

This should give the average percentage of each playlist's tracks that appears on the other playlist (by `artist` and `song_name`): thus 100% similarity if both playlists contain exactly the same tracks and 0% similarity iff there is no track that appears on both playlists.

Comment: Thank you, it is brilliant but I forgot to mention I need results  for a specific playlist.

Comment: @siniradam: Are you unable to adapt my answer accordingly?  It shouldn't be very difficult (and if you can't, you probably should run through a quick beginner's tutorial on SQL).

Comment: Sure I've updated, I just mentioned. Thank you.

SELECT   t1.playlistid, t2.playlistid,
         (
           1/COUNT(DISTINCT t1.singer, t1.singer)
         + 1/COUNT(DISTINCT t2.singer, t2.singer)
         )
         * SUM(t1.singer = t2.singer AND t1.singer = t2.singer)/2 similarity
FROM     tracks t1 JOIN tracks t2 ON t2.playlistid > t1.playlistid
WHERE t1.playlistid = 1 GROUP BY t1.playlistid, t2.playlistid